# Trying to schedule a function within an infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, schedule

So I have a loop running infinitely and want to send myself an email every 30 seconds to see how many times the loop has run.

```
x = 0
while 1;
   schedule.every(30).seconds.do(send_email, 'Update Email', str(x))
   x = x+1
   sleep(1)
   schedule.run_pending()
```

The send email function requires a subject and content input, which is achieved by the 'Update Email' and str(x) input respectively. However, due to the way the loop is formatted it doesn't update the variable x when it sends me the update. It simply sends me the same value over and over again. Plus since it is within the loop, I get a ton of emails every couple seconds since it is constantly looping. Is there a way that I can fix this so that I get an updated x value sent to me every 30 seconds?

Comment: I don't know exactly what your `schedule` is doing, and what this `every` is for. But, maybe you can check if x is a multiple of 30 before sending the mail, by using `if x % 30 == 0`.

Comment: first why there is semicolon at the end of while statement?
second, an initial raw idea, write the last value of X in a file, or variable, and put the schedule.every... statement in IF block, with condition if old_variable is NOT equal current_variable. then at the last statement update the variable or write it again to file...

May be other solution be found,also. but depends on you situations

Comment: What is `send_email` ?